# Cordova connect sqlite database from storage

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I have an sqlite database in my  `file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.myappxxxx/files/databases/app_db.db` location.

I am trying to connect this database using [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) with the bellow code

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'app_db.db', iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'},
function(){ 
  alert("success");
 },
function(){ 
 alert("failed");
});
```

The database connection was success ,but it is not connected to my `file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.myappxxxx/files/databases/app_db.db`,and create new blank database somewhere.I need to know how it is possible to connect my database.

Answer (score 1):

See on [Cordova-sqlite-storage Plugin Page](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage):

> To specify a different location (affects iOS only):
>
> var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db',
> iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'}, successcb, errorcb); where the
> iosDatabaseLocation option may be set to one of the following choices:
>
> `default`: `Library/LocalDatabase` subdirectory - NOT visible to iTunes and NOT backed up by iCloud
>
> `Library`: `Library` subdirectory - backed up by iCloud, NOT visible to iTunes
>
> `Documents`: `Documents` subdirectory - visible to iTunes and backed up by iCloud

Try to `Library/LocalDatabase` subdirectory:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'app_db.db', iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'},
function(){ 
  alert("success");
 },
function(){ 
 alert("failed");
});
```